# SSE matrix-matrix multiplication

Tags: c, sse, matrix-multiplication

I'm having trouble doing matrix-matrix multiplication with SSE in C.

Here is what I got so far:

```
#define N 1000

void matmulSSE(int mat1[N][N], int mat2[N][N], int result[N][N]) {
  int i, j, k;
  __m128i vA, vB, vR;

  for(i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    for(j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
        vR = _mm_setzero_si128();
        for(k = 0; k < N; k += 4) {
            //result[i][j] += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j];
            vA = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&mat1[i][k]);
            vB = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&mat2[k][j]); //how well does the k += 4 work here? Should it be unrolled?
            vR = _mm_add_epi32(vR, _mm_mul_epi32(vA, vB));
        }
        vR = _mm_hadd_epi32(vR, vR);
        vR = _mm_hadd_epi32(vR, vR);
        result[i][j] += _mm_extract_epi32(vR, 0);
    }
  }
}
```

I can't seem to make it give the correct results. Am I missing something?
And searching dosent seem to help much - every result is either only doing 4x4 matrices, mat-vec or some special magic thats not very readable and hard to understand...

Comment: What is the trouble you are having?

Comment: @RushyPanchal I'm not getting the correct results. Sorry, I should have specified that in my post...

Comment: Does the caller zero `result[]` for you?  If not, you should do that first!  Also note that doing a horizontal sum inside the inner-most loop is horrible.  If you do all the math for `result[i][j]` inside the same inner-most loop, just do `result = hsum(vR)`, not `+=`.  Where hsum is a horizontal-sum function that's portable to non-MSVC (if that matters) and sucks less than what the compiler probably produces for what you wrote.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-float-vector-sum-on-x86, where my answer mentions integer hsums.

Comment: Yeah its zeroed. And the += was mostly for basic testing. updated with hadd - is it along the lines of what you were talking about?

Comment: Well, `_mm_hadd_epi32` is not the most efficient way to do a horizontal sum (read the link in my last comment).  But yes, that's the right idea.  Why is it commented out, and why are you storing 4 copies of the result instead of just a scalar store of the horizontal sum to `result[i][j]`?

Comment: Oops, was doing some tests and commented it out - guess I copied it at a bad time. And I want to get it working properly first before looking at optimizing it even more. And I guess I was hoping to calculate result for 4 at once, but I see now that that doesnt work as well as I hoped it would. However it is still not working properly...Im heavily suspecting that the problem lies with how Im using vB....

Comment: Oh, yeah, you're loading 4 consecutive integers, but `mat2[k+0..3][j]` aren't contiguous.  Much has been written about optimizing matrix multiplies, with SIMD and with cache-blocking.  I suggest you google it up.  Most if it is probably talking about FP, but it all applies to integer as well.  (Except that SSE/AVX only has FMA for FP, not for 32-bit integers, and the 8 and 16-bit input PMADD instructions do horizontal adds of pairs.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, your `vB` is the problem.  You're loading 4 consecutive integers, but `mat2[k+0..3][j]` aren't contiguous.  You're actually getting `mat2[k][j+0..3]`.

---

I forget what works well for matmul.  Sometimes it works well to produce 4 results in parallel, instead of doing a horizontal sum for every result.

Transposing one of your input matrices works, and costs O(N^2).  It's worth it because it means the O(N^3) matmul can use sequential accesses, and your current loop structure becomes SIMD-friendly.

There are even better ways, such as transposing small blocks right before use, so they're still hot in L1 cache when you read them again.  Or looping over a destination row and adding in one result, instead of accumulating a full result for a single or small set of row*column dot products.  Cache blocking, aka loop tiling, is one key to good matmul performance.  See also [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126311/what-every-programmer-should-know-about-memory) which has a cache-blocked SIMD FP matmul example in an appendix without a transpose.

Much has been written about optimizing matrix multiplies, with SIMD and with cache-blocking.  I suggest you google it up.  Most if it is probably talking about FP, but it all applies to integer as well.

(Except that SSE/AVX only has FMA for FP, not for 32-bit integers, and the 8 and 16-bit input PMADD instructions do horizontal adds of pairs.)

---

Actually I think you can produce 4 results in parallel here, **if one input has been transposed already**:

```
void matmulSSE(int mat1[N][N], int mat2[N][N], int result[N][N]) {

  for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j+=4) {   // vectorize over this loop
        __m128i vR = _mm_setzero_si128();
        for(int k = 0; k < N; k++) {   // not this loop
            //result[i][j] += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j];
            __m128i vA = _mm_set1_epi32(mat1[i][k]);  // load+broadcast is much cheaper than MOVD + 3 inserts (or especially 4x insert, which your new code is doing)
            __m128i vB = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&mat2[k][j]);  // mat2[k][j+0..3]
            vR = _mm_add_epi32(vR, _mm_mullo_epi32(vA, vB));
        }
        _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)&result[i][j], vR));
    }
  }
}
```

A broadcast-load (or separate load+broadcast without AVX) is still much cheaper than a gather.

Your current code does the gather with 4 inserts, instead of breaking the dependency chain on the previous iteration's value by using a MOVD for the first element, so that's even worse.  But even the best gather of 4 scattered elements is pretty bad compared to a load + PUNPCKLDQ.  Not to mention that that makes your code need SSE4.1.

Although it needs SSE4.1 anyway for `_mm_mullo_epi32` instead of the widening [PMULDQ (`_mm_mul_epi32`)](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PMULDQ.html).

Note that integer multiply throughput is generally worse than FP multiply, especially on Haswell and later.  FP FMA units only have 24-bit wide multipliers per 32-bit element (for FP mantissas) so using those for 32x32=>32-bit integer requires splitting into two uops.

Comment: Yes, this was a big error. Along with this I also found that the multiplication in SSE didnt work as I thought it did - see my edit. Thanks for all the help. :)

Comment: @Erlisch: holy crap, now you have 2 PHADDD instructions inside the inner loop, and a scalar `+=`.  Did you benchmark that against scalar code?  It's probably slower.

Comment: @Erlisch: I just noticed that we can produce results for `j+0..3` in parallel, and that's a LOT more efficient than vectorizing over `k` with a gather.  Updated my answer.

Comment: Yes it was alot slower, but as I said I was making a working example first. Your version cut the time in more than half. It also looks like it could easily be changed to i-k-j loop order to get the vectorized loop innermost.

Comment: @Erlisch: Yes, but then instead of accumulating a result in a register, you'd have to load/add/store to `&result[i][j]` inside the inner loop.  It's probably better to simply produce 4 results in parallel from the inner loop.  You could maybe improve your cache utilization by doing 4 vectors of `j` values in parallel, to get more reuse of the broadcast-load, and so the inner loop uses all 64B of every cache line it touches in mat2 (assuming mat2 is 64B-aligned).  The current version uses only 16B of every cache line, with a strided access pattern.

Comment: I'm having deja-vu about doing 4 vectors in parallel to get more reuse of the broadcast-load; I'm pretty sure I've come up with this idea before for the same problem, or at least something extremely similar.

Answer (score 0):

This first version was posted by the OP as an edit to the question where it doesn't belong.  Moved it to a community-wiki answer just for posterity.

That first version is absolute garbage for performance, the worst possible way to vectorize, doing an hsum down to scalar inside the inner-most loop, and doing a manual gather with `insert_epi32` not even a 4x4 transpose.

---

**Update:**
Woho! I finally figured it out. Besides the errors in my logic (thanks for the help Peter Cordes) there was also the issue of `_mm_mul_epi32()` not working as I thought it did - I should've been using `_mm_mullo_epi32()` instead!

I know this is not the most effective code, but it was made to get it to work properly first - now I can move on to optimizing it.

(**Note, don't use this, it's very very slow**)

```
// editor's note: this is the most naive and horrible way to vectorize
void matmulSSE_inefficient(int mat1[N][N], int mat2[N][N], int result[N][N]) {
    int i, j, k;
    __m128i vA, vB, vR, vSum;

    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        for(j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
            vR = _mm_setzero_si128();
            for(k = 0; k < N; k += 4) {
                //result[i][j] += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j];
                vA = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&mat1[i][k]);
                          // less braindead would be to start vB with movd, avoiding a false dep and one shuffle uop.
                          // vB = _mm_cvtsi32_si128(mat2[k][j]);   // but this manual gather is still very bad
                vB = _mm_insert_epi32(vB, mat2[k][j], 0);     // false dependency on old vB
                vB = _mm_insert_epi32(vB, mat2[k + 1][j], 1);  // bad spatial locality
                vB = _mm_insert_epi32(vB, mat2[k + 2][j], 2);  // striding down a column
                vB = _mm_insert_epi32(vB, mat2[k + 3][j], 3);
                vR = _mm_mullo_epi32(vA, vB);
                vR = _mm_hadd_epi32(vR, vR);                // very slow inside the inner loop
                vR = _mm_hadd_epi32(vR, vR);
                result[i][j] += _mm_extract_epi32(vR, 0);

                //DEBUG
                //printf("vA: %d, %d, %d, %d\n", vA.m128i_i32[0], vA.m128i_i32[1], vA.m128i_i32[2], vA.m128i_i32[3]);
                //printf("vB: %d, %d, %d, %d\n", vB.m128i_i32[0], vB.m128i_i32[1], vB.m128i_i32[2], vB.m128i_i32[3]);
                //printf("vR: %d, %d, %d, %d\n", vR.m128i_i32[0], vR.m128i_i32[1], vR.m128i_i32[2], vR.m128i_i32[3]);
                //printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**End of extremely inefficient code originally written by the OP**

---

**Update 2:** converted the OP's example to an i-k-j loop order version. Required an extra load for vR and moving the store into the inner loop, but setting vA could be moved up a loop. Turned out faster.

```
// this is significantly better but doesn't do any cache-blocking
void matmulSSE_v2(int mat1[N][N], int mat2[N][N], int result[N][N]) {
    int i, j, k;
    __m128i vA, vB, vR;

    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        for(k = 0; k < N; ++k) {
            vA = _mm_set1_epi32(mat1[i][k]);
            for(j = 0; j < N; j += 4) {
                //result[i][j] += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j];
                vB = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&mat2[k][j]);
                vR = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&result[i][j]);
                vR = _mm_add_epi32(vR, _mm_mullo_epi32(vA, vB));
                _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)&result[i][j], vR);

                //DEBUG
                //printf("vA: %d, %d, %d, %d\n", vA.m128i_i32[0], vA.m128i_i32[1], vA.m128i_i32[2], vA.m128i_i32[3]);
                //printf("vB: %d, %d, %d, %d\n", vB.m128i_i32[0], vB.m128i_i32[1], vB.m128i_i32[2], vB.m128i_i32[3]);
                //printf("vR: %d, %d, %d, %d\n", vR.m128i_i32[0], vR.m128i_i32[1], vR.m128i_i32[2], vR.m128i_i32[3]);

                //printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**These assume N is a multiple of 4, the vector width**

If that's not the case, often it's easier to still pad your array storage to a multiple of the vector width, so there's padding at the end of each row and you can just use that simple `j < N; j += 4` loop condition.  You'll want to keep track of the real `N` size separately from the storage layout with a row stride that's a multiple of 4 or 8.

Otherwise you want a loop condition like `j < N-3`; j += 4`, and a scalar cleanup for the end of a row.

Or masking or keeping the last full vector in a register so you can `_mm_alignr_epi8` with a maybe-overlapping final vector that ends at the end of the row, and maybe do a vector store.  This is easier with AVX or especially AVX512 masking.

Comment: You code is correct but will work only for dimensions which are multiple of 4.Can the code be made to work for any dimensions?

Comment: @rojansudev: yes, you can do a scalar cleanup for the last `N & 3` elements of a row, if it's not a multiple of 4.  Or better pad your rows.  Updated the answer with some hints.